# Loading geojson markers into mapbox setting custom icon image

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm new to mapbox/leaflet and I think it's a pretty basic problem I'm fighting the last two days and though I've tried several ways I can't wrap my head around it.

I'm loading markers via geojson:

```
var ma_3 = L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadURL('./data/marathon/marker3x.geojson');
```

and then try to change properties like size or color according to the title used in the geojson data:

```
ma_3.on('ready', function(layer) {
                this.eachLayer(function(marker) {
            if (marker.toGeoJSON().properties.title === 'Verpflegung') {

                marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({                   
                    "marker-size": 'large'
                }));
            } else {
                marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({}));
            }

            marker.bindPopup(marker.toGeoJSON().properties.id + ', ' +
                marker.toGeoJSON().properties.title);
        });
    })
    .addTo(baseMap);
```

The geojson looks like this:

```
{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "marker-ie2tbbh05",
        "title": "Verpflegung",
        "description": "",
        "marker-size": "medium",
        "marker-color": "#b7ddf3",
        "marker-symbol": "marker-stroked"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          6.431395,
          51.19433
        ]
      },
```

Am I missing something because I've also tried giving the marker a new face by using

```
var icon_live = L.icon({ iconUrl: './img/icon-live.png', iconSize: [35,35] });
```

somewhere in the setIcon function but nothing seems to work.
If someone could please point me in right direction. It's really appriciated.

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your example?

Comment: I tried to extract the problem into a fiddle but it didn't work. I already found out that the overwrite happened because I used "if's" instead of "if else" for the other cases. what still is not working and can't wrap my head around is the method on how to attach the custom marker image.

Comment: Do you see any error in console?

Comment: the console has no error output so on this hand everything is ok. I guess where it comes down to is that I don't understand how to combine the if-conditions ( when title === blue, then set marker icon bird.png ) with the method to render the geoJSON. Do I need put something like setGeoJSON somewhere before or after the addTo function? Thanks for holding on to my problem anyway, @muzaffar

Comment: Have you checked that where you're setting the icon style, the code comes up there ie if `if (marker.toGeoJSON().properties.title === 'Verpflegung')` satisfy, console here something and check if it gets print

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's a typical beginners mistake and maybe it's just me but I found it pretty confusing in which context to use the several options of setIcon.
In the end I made it work using .on(layeradd) and marker.setIcon(pathToYourIcon).

```
ma_3.on('layeradd', function(layer) {
            this.eachLayer(function(marker) {
        if (marker.toGeoJSON().properties.title === 'Verpflegung') {
            marker.setIcon(icon_live);
        } 

        marker.bindPopup(marker.toGeoJSON().properties.id + ', ' +
            marker.toGeoJSON().properties.title);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this example yet?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Custom marker icons</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.2/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.2/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = '<your access token here>';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
    .setView([40, -74.50], 8);

var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

var geoJson = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-75.00, 40]
    },
    "properties": {
        "title": "Small astronaut",
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "/mapbox.js/assets/images/astronaut1.png",
            "iconSize": [50, 50], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [25, 25], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [0, -25], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
        }
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-74.00, 40]
    },
    "properties": {
        "title": "Big astronaut",
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "/mapbox.js/assets/images/astronaut2.png",
            "iconSize": [100, 100],
            "iconAnchor": [50, 50],
            "popupAnchor": [0, -55],
            "className": "dot"
        }
    }
}];

// Set a custom icon on each marker based on feature properties.
myLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    var marker = e.layer,
        feature = marker.feature;

    marker.setIcon(L.icon(feature.properties.icon));
});

// Add features to the map.
myLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Source: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/custom-marker/